# Native query support is not enabled in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, kundera

I am new to kundera mongoDb,My problem is when i tried to get the data using native query i am getting below error

```
  Exception in thread "main" com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryHandlerException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Native query support is not enabled in mongoDB
    at com.impetus.client.mongodb.query.MongoDBQuery.populateEntities(MongoDBQuery.java:172)
    at com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryImpl.fetch(QueryImpl.java:986)
    at com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:163)
    at com.test.Test2.main(Test2.java:80)
```

My code is below

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("mango");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("db.resturant.find({contact: {\"$elemMatch\" :  {\"Mobile\" : \"9568256549\"}}})");

query.getResultList();
```

Help me...

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links:
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/212
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/248

HTH,
-Vivek

Comment: Thank you for your replay vivek,Still i have a problem can you please check the below link https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/683

Comment: Replied on github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/683